# Code for creating index named stu_sub_ind

Tags: sql

what is the code that will create an index named stu_sub_ind on the columns roll_num and subject of the student_subjects table?

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - he has no time for such details, he just wants the *magic* answer.

Comment: Read the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 create index stu_sub_ind on student_subjects(roll_num, subject);
```